# Perfomance: Switch vs Polymorphism

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, polymorphism, v8, vtable

I usually prefer polymorphism instead of switch when it possible. I find it more readable and it requires fewer lines. I believe these facts are enough to continue to use it. But what about performance? I've create a pretty simple (and bad) bench and it looks that switch is faster in my case. Could you please explain why?

https://jsfiddle.net/oqzpfqcg/1/

```
var class1 = { GetImportantValue: () => 1 };
var class2 = { GetImportantValue: () => 2 };
var class3 = { GetImportantValue: () => 3 };
var class4 = { GetImportantValue: () => 4 };
var class5 = { GetImportantValue: () => 5 };

getImportantValueSwitch = (myClassEnum) => {
    switch (myClassEnum.type) {
        case 'MyClass1': return 1;
        case 'MyClass2': return 2;
        case 'MyClass3': return 3;
        case 'MyClass4': return 4;
        case 'MyClass5': return 5;
    }
}

getImportantValuePolymorphism = (myClass) => myClass.GetImportantValue();

test = () => {
    var INTERATION_COUNT = 10000000;

    var t0 = performance.now();
    for (var i = 0; i < INTERATION_COUNT; i++) {
        getImportantValuePolymorphism(class1);
        getImportantValuePolymorphism(class2);
        getImportantValuePolymorphism(class3);
        getImportantValuePolymorphism(class4);
        getImportantValuePolymorphism(class5);
    }
    var t1 = performance.now();

    var t2 = performance.now();
    for (var i = 0; i < INTERATION_COUNT; i++) {
        getImportantValueSwitch({type: 'MyClass1'});
        getImportantValueSwitch({type: 'MyClass2'});
        getImportantValueSwitch({type: 'MyClass3'});
        getImportantValueSwitch({type: 'MyClass4'});
        getImportantValueSwitch({type: 'MyClass5'});
    }
    var t3 = performance.now();
    var first = t1 - t0;
    var second = t3 - t2;
    console.log("The first sample took " + first + " ms");
    console.log("The second sample took " + second + " ms");
    console.log("first / second =  " + (first/second));
};
test();
```

So as far as I understand the first sample has one dynamic/virtual runtime call `myClass.GetImportantValue()` and that's it. But the second has one dynamic/virtual runtime call as well `myClassEnum.type` and then **check the condition** in the switch.

Most probably I have some mistakes in the code but I cannot find it. The only thing that I suppose can affect result is `performance.now()`. But I think it does not affect so much.

Comment: You should consider using a purpose-built benchmarking tool rather than iterations like this. I've taken the liberty of create [a benchmark on MeasureThat.net](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/3121/0/perfomance-switch-vs-polymorphism). This also shows that switch is faster, at least in Chrome 66 on Win 10. That said, performance is very much a "it depends" kind of thing, and at the number of operations per second you're looking at here, the difference is negligible.

Comment: Three comments: (1) Micro-benchmark red flag. (2) Your switch loop  includes object creation. (3) This is dynamic dispatch, not polymorphism, which is about using different types.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg (1) Agree with you. (2) Anyways the switch is faster here and most probably it will be inlined (3) Agree about multiple dispatch but there are different types. So the same contract and different behaviors. It looks as some kind of polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V8 developer here. Your intuition is right: this microbenchmark isn't very useful.

One issue is that all your "classes" have the same shape, so the "polymorphic" case is in fact monomorphic. (If you fix this, be aware that V8 has vastly different performance characteristics for <= 4 and >= 5 polymorphic cases!)

One issue is that you're relying on on-stack replacement (OSR) for optimization, so the performance impact of that pollutes your timings in a misleading way -- especially for functions that have this pattern of two subsequent long-running loops: they get OSR-optimized for the first loop, deoptimized in the middle, then OSR-optimized again for the second loop.

One issue is that the compiler inlines many things, so the actually executed machine code can have a very different structure from the JavaScript code you wrote. In particular in this case, `getImportantValueSwitch` gets inlined, the `{type: 'MyClass*'}` constant object creations get elided, and the resulting code is just a few comparisons, which are very fast.

One issue is that with small functions, call overhead pretty much dominates everything else. V8's optimizing compiler doesn't currently do polymorphic inlining (because that's not always a win), so significant time is spent calling the `() => 1` etc functions. That's *unrelated* to the fact that they're dynamically dispatched -- retrieving the right function from the object is pretty fast, calling it is what has the overhead. For larger functions, you wouldn't notice it much, but for almost-empty functions, it's quite significant compared to the `switch`-based alternative that doesn't do *any* calls.

Long story short: in microbenchmarks, one tends to measure weird effects unrelated to what one intended to measure; and in larger apps, most implementation details like this one don't have measurable impact. Write the code that makes sense to you (is readable, maintainable, etc), let the JavaScript engine worry about the rest! *(Exception: Sometimes profiling indicates that your app has a particular bottleneck -- in such cases, hand-optimizing things can have big impact, but that's usually achieved by taking context into account and making the overall algorithm / control flow more efficient, rather than following simple rules of thumb like "prefer polymorphism over switch statements" (or the other way round).)*

Answer (score -1):

I do not see a "mistake" in your script. Although I really do not encourage performance testing this way, I might still be able to say a couple of things based on my intuition. I do not have solid, well tested results with control groups etc so take everything I say with a pinch of salt.

Now, for me it is quite normal to assume that the first option is gonna eat the dust of the second because there are couple of things more expensive than variable access in js:

- object property access (presumably O(1) hash table, but still slower than variable access)
- function call

If we count the function call and object access:

- first case: 5 call [to `getImportantValuePolymorphism`] x (1 object access [to `myClass`]  + 1 function call [to `GetImportantValue`] ===> **TOTAL OF 10 function calls + 5 object access**
- second case: 5 call [to `getImportantValueSwitch` ] + 5 object access [to `MyClassEnum`] ===> **TOTAL 5 function calls + 5 object access**

One more things to mention, that in the first case, you have a function that calls another function so you end up with a **scope chain**. Net effect of this is minute, but still detrimental in means of performance.

If we account all the above factors, first will be slower. But how much? That is not easy to answer as it will depend on vendor implementations but in your case it about 25 times slower in chrome. Assuming we have **double the function calls in the first case and a scope chain**, one would expect it to be 2 or 3 times slower, but not 25.

This exponential decrease in performance I presume is due to the fact that you are **starving the event loop**, meaning that when you give a synchronous task to js, since it is single threaded, if the task is a cumbersome one, the event loop cannot proceed and gets stuck for good second or so. This question comes around when people see strange behavior of setTimeout or other async calls when they fire way off from the target time frame. This is as I said, due to the fact that previous synchronous task is taking way too long. In your case you have a synchronous for loop that iterates 10 million times.

To test my hypothesis, decrease the `ITERATION_COUNT` to 100000, that is 100 times less, you will see that in chrome, the ratio will decrase from ~20 to ~2. So the bottom line 1: *Part of the inefficiency you observe is stemming from the fact that you are starving the event loop, but it still does not change the fact that first option is slower*.

To test that function calls are indeed the bottle neck here, change the relevant parts of your script to this:

```
class1 = class1.GetImportantValue;
class2 = class2.GetImportantValue;
class3 = class3.GetImportantValue;
class4 = class4.GetImportantValue;
class5 = class5.GetImportantValue;
```

and for the test:

```
for (var i = 0; i < INTERATION_COUNT; i++) {
        class1();
        class2();
        class3();
        class4();
        class5();
    }
```

Resulting fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/oqzpfqcg/2/

This time you will see that the first one is faster because it is (5 function calls) vs  ( 5 function calls + 5 object access).

Comment: Your intuition is partially right (function calls have a cost) and partially wrong: (1) object property accesses are not generally slower than variable accesses (they can even be faster, it depends), (2) scope chains have no performance impact, (3) starving the event loop matters for remaining responsive to user input, but has nothing to do with the performance of long-running workloads.

Comment: 1-object property access is slower or equal to variable access at best and this will depend on what the property is AND how deep the property is nested withing the object. Otherwise we would not need to cache an object's property within a function. 2-Js searches for variables starting from the closest scope up to the parent scope. I said in my own answer that it is 'minute' but nonetheless there is, there must be because simply more work is done. 3-I thought exactly like you until I plotted the ratio vs the loop count. My take home,the inefficiency is amplified the more event loop is blocked.

Comment: @ibowankenobi (1) I see 5 function calls + 5 object access **per iteration** in both cases. But the first one use polymorphic object access. (2) Your sample doesn't use polymorphism that's why we have better performance. Unfortunately we cannot use it as alternative to switch.

Comment: @Serg046 first case is 10 function calls. What you refer to polymorphic object access in the end resolves to a function call, and it is just as taxing as a function call. The only difference is that context of 'this' remains same. If you think it is more beneficial than a function call you can do all the tests you want, it'll prove you otherwise --> it is just a function call.

Comment: Yes but it is a virtual call and cannot be inlined as V8's developer said in another answer. So it has bigger cost.

Comment: it is correct, however this does even make your case weaker. Replace the method call with a cached function, and it will still be slower. The bottle neck is the function call itself, not that it is anonymous call/cached call/method call. Also the degree of performance difference you observe is not just due to this, but the fact that you are hanging the browser (starving the loop) for a second or so. Change the iteration count and record the ratio yourself, you will usually get exponentially increasing   values >1. Don't you think it is significant??